# Connecting Angular-CLI with Express

Tags: node.js, express, angular

I generated an Angular2 project by using Angular-CLI. This is the front-end side. Now I'd like to add an Express server but I don't know how exactly should I do that.

Should I add an express app.js file into generated by Angualar-CLI "src" directory? I've tried it and what's next? To start Angular-CLI project, I need to type `ng serve` in CMD. To start server, I need to type `node app.js`.

Example of app.js

```
var express = require('express'),
    path = require('path'),
    favicon = require('serve-favicon'),
    logger = require('morgan'),
    cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});

app.listen("8080", function() {
  console.log("at 8080 port");
});

module.exports = app;
```

Well... Angular2 doesn't work when I start app by `node app.js`. `ng serve` builds all files and in mysterious for me way puts it all together.

Maybe I should create front-end and back-end completely separated? But what then? Use technology like Nginx for reverse proxy?

Comment: Why would you need a reverse proxy? For development, just have them served on separate ports on localhost. In general the front end and back end can be completely separate, they just talk over an API.

Comment: reverse proxy recommended for production & testing only not for development. You should run both as a separate project on different port

Comment: Okay but in some way I need to let them communicate with each other, right? I haven't done many projects like that. If I have front-end on 3000, backend on 8080, how could I make a request and respond?

Comment: Just e.g. `http.get('http://localhost:8080/whatever/endpoint')`. Express won't be serving the HTML, just providing an API; you'd probably be better off just using vanilla Node.JS, might be less confusing.